# AG Grid unit testing that gridApi functions are called (ie: gridApi.setQuickFilter)

Tags: angular, jasmine, ag-grid

I have a function that calls `gridApi.setQuickFilter', and I need to test that it is getting called with the correct arguments.

component:

```
  clearQuickFilter = () => {
    this.quickFilter = '';
    this.gridApi.setQuickFilter('');
  };
```

My attempt at a unit test for this gives me an error `Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for setQuickFilter()` and unfortunately I haven't been able to resolve this.

spec.ts:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [AgGridModule],
      providers: [...],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('quick filters', () => {
    it('should clear quickfilters', () => {
      const quickFilterSpy = spyOn(
        component.gridApi,
        'setQuickFilter'
      );  // the test fails on this line with the error above

      component.clearQuickFilter();

      expect(component.quickFilter).toBe('');
      expect(quickFilterSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('');
    });
  });
});
```

How can I mock gridApi functions like `setQuickFilter` and others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mock object, then the error will go away. During testing gridApi will not have values, we need to mock the object also!

the below change will get rid of your error!

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [AgGridModule],
      providers: [...],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('quick filters', () => {
    it('should clear quickfilters', () => {
      component.gridApi = { // <-- changed here
          setQuickFilter: () => {}, // <-- changed here
      } as any; // <-- changed here
      const quickFilterSpy = spyOn(
        component.gridApi,
        'setQuickFilter'
      );

      component.clearQuickFilter();

      expect(component.quickFilter).toBe('');
      expect(quickFilterSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('');
    });
  });
});
```